# check for values and only values listed must be present in column VBA

Tags: vba

I want make sure only N or Y are preset in these columns and both N and Y must be present in the columns i am having issues with second part of both being present it does not give me error if only N or Y is present because it passes the first argument. pls help how can i adjust code to pick up both arguments.

```
     Sub Check_For_Y_N()

        Dim c As Range
        Dim lr As Long

        lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each c In Range("L2:L3" & lr & ",Y2:Y3" & lr)

            If c.Value <> "Y" And c.Value <> "N" And c.Value <> "" Then
            
                MsgBox "Incorrect Values " & c.Address
              
            End If 
 
        Next c

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So the only valid input is either

1. `Column L = "Y"` and `Column Y = "N"`
2. `Column L = "N"` and `Column Y = "Y"`

You can test for the above statement with `OR` to make sure the value combination is one of the above options.

Your variable range is not correct but I took a different approach (*`For i` rather `For Each`*) so will not address that since it's not the pain problem of your question.

---

```
Sub How()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If (ws.Range("L" & i) = "Y" And ws.Range("Y" & i) = "N") Or (ws.Range("L" & i) = "N" And ws.Range("Y" & i) = "Y") Then
        'Valid Values
    Else
        'Invalid Values
        MsgBox "Invalid values in row " & i
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: is there way to use with i so i can know where error occurred ?

Comment: Yes, where I have `Invalid Values` is where you would put your code when the values don't match your criteria. So replace my line there with whatever you want to do with an error

Comment: how would i adjust to look just in 1 column 'L' instead i took out part of the argument but does not work for me (ws.Range("L" & i) = "Y" And ws.Range("L" & i) = "N")

Comment: You want `OR` not `AND`. Column L cannot be Y & N at the sand time which is what the AND is looking for in your statement

Comment: there should both 'N' and 'Y' present in column 'L' and only  values N' or 'Y' in  column 'L' both logics must pass or error

Comment: Post sample data and show problem. It shouldn’t take this many back and forths so will pause until you can show me the problem

Comment: with this code if all Y's or all N's are present it does not give me error which is what i want to happen when both are not present in column :

Comment: Sub search_N_Y()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If (ws.Range("L" & i) = "Y" Or ws.Range("L" & i) = "N") Then
        'Valid Values
    Else
        'Invalid Values
        MsgBox "Invalid values in row " & i
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Comment: @ urdearboy this what should always be in column                                                              Column L Plan's Evaluation of Timeliness
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
N
N
N
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y
Y

Comment: Sharing code obviously has not explained the issue well. From what I can tell, my solution answers the question you initially posted so it seems you are changing the criteria on us which makes it hard to ever give you the answer you are looking for. Post photo on your question of the problem. Show data and what the expected output should be and where the macro fails to work. Not even going to look at code anymore. It's easier for me to just see the problem

Comment: @ urdearboy  not sure i understand fully what your saying but thanks anyways